# Put a vertical arrow on the one column table

Tags: tables, arrows, algorithms, pseudocode

I made a simple table with one column and I want to imitate the pseudocode.

My code is like this:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Algorithm for CNN Architecture}
\label{tab:fonts}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
Input: DEM\\ 
\hspace{5mm} Conv 3x3, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{10mm} MaxPool 2x2\\
\hspace{10mm} Conv 3x3, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{15mm} MaxPool 2x2\\
\hspace{15mm} Conv 3x3, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{20mm} MaxPool 2x2\\
\hspace{20mm} Conv 3x3, ReLU\\
\hspace{20mm} Up-conv 2x2\\ 
\hspace{15mm} Copy\\
\hspace{15mm} Dropout, then conv 3x3, ReLU\\
\hspace{15mm} Conv 3x3, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{15mm} Up-conv 2x2\\ 
\hspace{10mm} Copy\\
\hspace{10mm} Dropout, then conv 3x3, ReLU\\
\hspace{10mm} Conv 3x3, ReLU\\
\hspace{10mm} Up-conv 2x2\\ 
\hspace{5mm} Copy\\
\hspace{5mm} Dropout, then conv 3x3, ReLU\\
\hspace{5mm} Conv 3x3, ReLU\\
\hspace{5mm} Conv 1x1, sigmoid\\ 
Output: Predicted Mask\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And what I want is like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i) please extend your code fragment to complete document beginning with `\documentclass ...` and ending with `\end{environment}`, (ii) instead this table try to use for pseudo codes dedicated package `algorithmic`  from the `algorithms` bundle

Answer (score 2):

Welome to TeX.SE! This a proposal based on your tabular. There might be more elegant ways to typeset this tabular, though. The answer is using `tikzmark` to mark the `C`'s you want to connect, and the an overlay Ti*k*Z picture to draw the arrows between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Algorithm for CNN Architecture}
\label{tab:fonts}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
Input: DEM\\ 
\hspace{5mm} \tikzmarknode{C1}{C}onv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{10mm} MaxPool $2{\times}2$\\
\hspace{10mm} \tikzmarknode{C2}{C}onv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{15mm} MaxPool $2{\times}2$\\
\hspace{15mm} \tikzmarknode{C3}{C}onv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{20mm} MaxPool $2{\times}2$\\
\hspace{20mm} Conv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\
\hspace{20mm} Up-conv $2{\times}2$\\ 
\hspace{15mm} \tikzmarknode{C3'}{C}opy\\
\hspace{15mm} Dropout, then conv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\
\hspace{15mm} Conv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\ 
\hspace{15mm} Up-conv $2{\times}2$\\ 
\hspace{10mm} \tikzmarknode{C2'}{C}opy\\
\hspace{10mm} Dropout, then conv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\
\hspace{10mm} Conv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\
\hspace{10mm} Up-conv $2{\times}2$\\ 
\hspace{5mm} \tikzmarknode{C1'}{C}opy\\
\hspace{5mm} Dropout, then conv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\
\hspace{5mm} Conv $3{\times}3$, ReLU\\
\hspace{5mm} Conv $1{\times}1$, sigmoid\\ 
Output: Predicted Mask\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw[red,-latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (C\X.south) -- (C\X'.north);} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply but why my `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` is not working?

Comment: @RushSina I don't know. When was the last time you updated your TeX installation?